# Eigenvalue and eigen vector of covariance matrix in mean*mean'

Tags: covariance, eigenvalues

I know the rank of $\Sigma^{-1}m m'$ is $1$. How can I find the eigenvalue and eigenvector of it? ($\Sigma^{-1}$ is the inverse of a covariance matrix and $m$ is a mean vector.)

Answer (score 5):

Apply the definitions: a *nonzero* vector $x$ is an eigenvector of a matrix $\mathbb{A}$ means there exists a scalar $\lambda$ such that $\mathbb{A}x = \lambda x.$  (Eigenvectors are defined only up to nonzero scalar multiples.)  When this is the case, $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue associated with (all nonzero multiples of) $x$.  Whence, letting $\mathbb{A} = \Sigma^{-1}mm',$ we seek a vector $x$ for which

$$\Sigma^{-1}mm'x = \lambda x.$$

Notice that $m'x$ is a *scalar.*  This means the left hand side is a scalar multiple of the vector $\Sigma^{-1}m$, which is nonzero *provided $m$ is nonzero* (an auxiliary assumption we will have to make).  Consequently **$x$ must be a multiple of $\Sigma^{-1}m.$**  Let's check:

$$\left(\Sigma^{-1}mm'\right)(\Sigma^{-1}m) = \left(\Sigma^{-1}m\right)\left(m'\Sigma^{-1}m\right).$$

Sure enough, the right hand side is a multiple of $\Sigma^{-1}m$ and the multiple is explicitly given as **$m'\Sigma^{-1}m$, which is the desired eigenvalue.**

This analysis holds for any square matrix $\Sigma^{-1}$ and any vector $m$ for which $\Sigma^{-1}m$ is nonzero.